# Проблема с маршрутизацией в джанго

Tags: django

Попробую на словах объяснить суть. Создал меню и левый сайдбар со ссылками, все  работает. Затем добавил модель Article. А теперь мои действия, после которых заглючило.
За главную страницу отвечало представление с TemplateView, я переделал его на ListView и отображаю на ней экземпляры Article. Это работает.
Затем сделал представление ArticleDetail со своим url, тоже работает.
Но теперь почему-то при переходе по другим ссылкам возникает ошибка 404.
Raised by:  views.ArticleDetail
Почему ArticleDetail вызывается, ведь не должно?

```
settings.urls
        path('', include('app1.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('users/', include('app2.urls')),
        path('forum/', include('app3.urls')),
```

В сообщении об ошибке выдает url, которые найдены

```
[name='main_page']
<slug:article_slug>/ [name='article']
```

Но их должно быть порядка 15-ти. Что не так с ArticleDetail?

Comment: Поменял местами последовательность url-ов во всех urls.py и заработало. Только не понятно почему это так важно?

Answer (score 1):

Порядок важен. Если вы орбрабатываете строку url. Уверен у вас в `app1.urls` есть стрoка `path('<slug:slug>/', ...)` или что то подобное. Так как `slug` - набор букв, цифр и некоторых других знаков, `django` пытается найти обработать этот `url` так как адрес запроса полностью подошел к шаблону `url`. А так как объекта с таким `slug` (или какое поле вы там получаете) нет, выходит 404 ошибка.

Учитывайте, что Django ищет первое совпадение под шаблон, и если такое случилось, все ниже стоящие не будут проверены.

И да, это написано в документации, если поискать про `urlpatterns` )

Comment: Спасибо, учту на будущее.